# Optimising Minimax for a Game

Tags: dynamic-programming, minimax, game-theory

I'm currently trying to solve a programming problem using minimax with alpha-beta-pruning.
The game is represented as a tree with a defined root. Each node has a given cost. Each node can have an amount of childs bigger than 0 if its not a leaf. The game has to end at a leaf.

Player A wants to maximize the cost he can receive by traversing the tree. He can choose to stay at the current node, or go to one of its childs.
Player B wants to minimize the cost, but he has to choose a child and can't pass unlike Player A.
Both Players play optimally.

I have implemented a solution, which does return the desired results, but is too slow after a certain amount of nodes, leading to a timeout.
My idea would be to somehow save the results of the previous minimax search for the given tree, but that only helps if Player A chooses to advance, otherwise I would have to do the minimax search again.

```
vector<int> edges[MAXN];
int minimax(int node, bool p1_turn, int alpha, int beta) {
    if(edges[node].empty()) return cost[node];

    if(p1_turn) {
        int best = minimax(node, false, alpha, beta);
        for(auto u: edges[node]) {
            int val = minimax(u, false, alpha, beta);
            best = max(val, best);
            alpha = max(alpha, best);

            if(beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            } 
        
        }
        return best;
    } else {
        int best = MAX_INF;
        for(auto u: edges[node]){
            int val = minimax(u, true, alpha, beta);
            best = min(best, val);
            beta = min(best, beta);

            if(beta <= alpha){
                break;
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}


...
minimax(1, true, MIN_INF, MAX_INF)
...
```

Applying the above algorithm returns the desired results, but is too slow after a certain amount of nodes.

**EDIT**

Changed the inner if-block to be more in line with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode

```
    if(edges[node].empty()) return cost[node];
    if(p1_turn) {
        int best = minimax(node, false, alpha, beta);
        for(auto u: edges[node]) {
            best = max(best, minimax(u, false, alpha, beta));
            if(best > beta) {
                break;
            }
            alpha = max(alpha, best);        
        }
        return best;
    } else {
        int best = MAX_INF;
        for(auto u: edges[node]){
            best = min(best, minimax(u, true, alpha, beta));
            if(best < alpha){
                break;
            }
            beta = min(best, beta);
        }
        return best;
    }
```

Comment: What game are you using it for?

Comment: This is for an assignment, the "game" is actually just two players trying to get the maximum/minimum possible cost for chocolate, where the chocolate are the nodes

Comment: I see, so the "game" is just the minimax itself? Are you sure the code is correct, it looks different than https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning. Also, how do you determine if there is another node beneath the current one? I mena, how do you get all possible "moves"?

Comment: I have changed my answer to be more inline with the wikipedia pseudocode. 2 things are different, 1. I dont use the depth, since i tried that before but got the wrong answer, presumably because the input provided is too deep, 2. in the maximizers turn i do a minimax search from the given node, not a child, because Player 1 can choose to stay at the starting node. The "moves" are given through a series of inputs, consisting of "p_i c_i" on line i for node i

Comment: "N lines describing the brands, with the i-th line containing two numbers
ai and ci (0 ≤ ai ≤ N, 0 < ci ≤ 10^9; a1 = 0) – ancestor and cost of the
i-th chocolate." is the relevant specificatior for the possible moves. Node 1 is the starting node

Comment: If you already got alpha-beta, the next optimisation is move ordering (look at moves that are likely to be good first). For more optimisations look at [this](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page), it is for chess specifically but there are some idea that might apply.